# How to define Boolean values in Racket?

Tags: boolean, racket

**In racket true is already a keyword and the question asks me to multiply if the value is true **
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srkIL.jpg)

Comment: Are we talking about Racket or one of the teaching languages?

Comment: I am talking about racket

Answer (score 2):

In Racket the *literals* `#t` and `#f` will evaluate to the true and the false value respectively. Note that constructs such as `if` use the convention that any non-false value will count as a true value. Only the false value will trigger the else-branch.

Read more in the Guide: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/booleans.html

Answer (score 1):

For source files in DrRacket that are written in `#lang racket`, thus the definition has that as the first line, we have the following [documentation from the reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?q=%23true#%28part._parse-boolean%29):

> A `#true`, `#t`, `#T` followed by a delimiter is the input syntax for the
>   boolean constant “true,” and `#false`, `#f`, or `#F` followed by a delimiter
>   is the complete input syntax for the boolean constant “false.”

Since you can write in other languages in racket (that `#lang racket`) the other languages might have other literals to represent true and false booleans. eg. in Advanced student, *a complete different language than `#lang racket`*, you can use the variables `true` and `false` that when evaluated displays as `#true` and `#false`.